# How to separate views from component in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, The component looks very messy it has views, controller and styles everything in one file.

I want to organise these things in a separate file, like Write views (UI design) in separate files and styles in a separate file and want to import into components( How we do it in Angular projects)

Like this

**UPDATE**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-outcome-ratio-popup',
  templateUrl: './outcome-ratio-popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./outcome-ratio-popup.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class OutcomeRatioPopupComponent implements OnInit {
//i write logics  here
}
```

in outcome-ratio-popup.component.html

```
<div>hello world <div>  //i write view design code here
```

outcome-ratio-popup.component.scss

```
ul{
      li{
          margin-top: 10px;  //i Write styles here
      }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Reusable View blocks can be added to seperate block components say for example Profile, Which holds the Profile block and call each with parametes as user data. Style you can create seperate js file and can be imported as required.

Comment: Take a look at this nice [React Native boilerplate](https://github.com/thecodingmachine/react-native-boilerplate). It will help you to understand the whole folder structure.

Comment: @Ajith can you please  give me any example

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am currently following for my projects.
in root directory you can have folder 'app' which will have following structure

[image: Project Structure]

*Edited*

Suppose you have component name Header

Header

- Index.js ( you can right component app logic here)
- Style.js ( style for your component )
- View.js ( view for your component )

I personally will not recommend above layout.

---

You can use following
Heder

- Index.js ( you can right component app logic & view here)
- Style.js ( style for your component )

Mostly in react-native we don’t kept view and logic in separate file because component file will contain very little amount of logic. And if your component is very huge you can try to break down component into small component. That will declutter your components.

if you can take look at [this](https://github.com/rishikeshgaikar/RNews) project and you will understand what i am  trying to say

Comment: Thank you Rishikesh,You have separated styles from component can you please tell how to separate views also from component.

Comment: I didn't get you?

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check.You might get better understanding.

Comment: If you don't get please feel free to ask again.

Comment: ohk i got it. You want to separate view, style from the component and write only login in component and import views and styles in it right?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot. Please check.

Comment: thanks for the answer. could you please tell me how to import view.js in the component.

Comment: import View from './View.js'

Comment: @rishikesh_07  But I want seprate file for view and my logic in seprate file how we can do it?  I am not able to use buttonclick function declared in component from my view.

Comment: @Ankita check your onPress in view and logic in view it should be like onPress={()=> yourmethod} and in login it simply like onPress={onPress from View}